# Min and max of n sets of numbers

Tags: c++

I am supposed to write a program in C++ which will find maximum and minimum of n sets of numbers in the following way:

1. The first input is a positive integer n = the number of 5-element sets of numbers. That is, we want to have n lines of numbers, 5 (real) numbers in each line.
2. Each set of numbers consists of 5 numbers separated by a space bar.
3. As a result we want to find for each of the n sets its maximum, minimum and arithmetic mean.

Here is my attempt:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int n;
float maxx, minn, a;

int main()
{
    cin >> n;

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)

    {

        float T[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cin >> T[i];
        }

        if (T[0] > T[1]) {
            maxx = T[0];
            minn = T[1];
        }
        else {
            maxx = T[1];
            minn = T[0];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 2) {

            if (T[i + 2] > T[i + 3]) {
                if (T[i + 2] > maxx) {
                    maxx = T[i + 2];
                    if (T[i + 3] < minn) {
                        minn = T[i + 3];
                    }
                }
            }
            else {

                if (T[i + 3] > maxx) {
                    maxx = T[i + 3];
                    if (T[i + 2] < minn) minn = T[i + 2];
                }
            }
        }
        a = (T[0] + T[1] + T[2] + T[3] + T[4]) / 5.0;

        cout << maxx << endl;
        cout << minn << endl;
        cout << a << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is what happens after correcting i, j=1, i, j ++ into i, j=0 and changing the algorithm for min and max:

[image]

As you can see, the calculations are done correctly this time, but there is still a problem with the loop.

Could you tell me what is wrong with my solution? How can I fix it?

**OK! IT WORKS JUST FINE NOW! THANK YOU A LOT FOR ALL YOUR HELP AND PATIENCE!**

Comment: why are n and i global variables?

Comment: And where is `j` defined? What `swap` function are you using? What header files do you include? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Arrays start at index 0, not 1.  Ex: `for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++)` is wrong, unless you subtract 1 from `i` within the loop when indexing the array.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "still input more numbers"? Can you please show us a sample session? with actual input and output, as well as expected output?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've just added a screenshot of what happens after compiling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written, your code results in undefined behavior, because it is going to corrupt the stack memory.

```
float T[5];

for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    cin >> T[i];
}
```

This obviously results in undefined behavior. This may or may not be your actual bug, but until this bug is fixed (and this bug is repeated several times, in the following code), you cannot expect any defined behavior from your program.

Comment: @SIlverstripeNewbie That's the problem with undefined behavior, the behavior is *undefined* and can't be predicted. This could very well have been the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you enter `2` for `n`, then the outer loop (`for(int j=0; j<n; j++)`) will run two times, letting you enter the five numbers for calculations twice. That's how you coded it. If it's not supposed to be like that then you need to rethink the solution about the problem you try to solve.

Answer (score 1):

```
float T[5];

for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    cin >> T[i];
}
```

Each and every array starts with an index 0.
For example if you declare an integer array say `int a[10]`;
It's starting address is say 1000.
Then the memory location goes like this:

For first element  `a[0]   1000+0*size of int`

For second element `a[1]   1000+1*size of int`

For third element  `a[2]   1000+2*size of int`....... and so on.

In this example you have started with `T[1]`, which is starting `address+1*size of float`, which is logically the second element

Answer (score 1):

According to your code you have to enter the other set of numbers after you get max, min and average.

Comment: Is there a way to enter two lines of numbers one after the other and then get two lines of results?

Comment: Yes. Use 2-D arrays to input data. Here in this case it will be nx5.

Comment: I see. What if I am not allowed to use these [ ] brackets in my code? Is there a way to write two lines one after the other? (Then I would have to change T[0], ..., T[4] to a, ..., e)

Comment: If you don't want to use [ ] then you have to declare those many variables. Which is tedious. For example if you want a 2-D array with 5 rows and 5 columns without using [ ] i,e. arrays then you need to declare 5x5=25 different variables. That is were arrays comes into picture.

Answer (score 1):

You currently have out of bound accesses (`T[i + 2] > T[i + 3]` where `i == 3`).

split in sub-function may help:

```
void max_min_mean_5()
{
    float values[5];

    for (auto& value : values) {
        std::cin >> value;
    }

    const auto p = std::minmax_element(std::begin(values), std::end(values));
    const auto mean = std::accumulate(std::begin(values), std::end(values), 0.f) / 5.f;
    std::cout << *p.second << std::endl;
    std::cout << *p.first << std::endl;
    std::cout << mean << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        max_min_mean_5();
    }
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/YdYNfG).

Answer (score -6):

change

```
for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
```

to

```
for(j=1; j<=n; ++j)
```

Because `j++` evaluates to prior `j` value, `++j` evaluates to the just incremented value.

Comment: This makes no difference, whatsoever, in this example. Wrong answer.

Comment: The three expression in a `for` loop are done at different times, you could almost look at them as three different and separate sub-statements.